# Weblogic Oracle Service Bus 11gR1 NoClassDefFoundError Hibernate Exception

Tags: oracle, hibernate, weblogic11g, osb

We have a Business Service which we have imported from a Weblogic OSB 10.3 server into a Weblogic OSB 11gR1 server. The Business Service is an ejb protocol service which basically connects to an Oracle DB and writes messages to a given Table.

When we call the Business Service from a project flow, we are getting the following exception:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/JDBCException`

thus, the messages in the flow are not being written to the database table...

I am guessing that this is due to a wrong hibernate jar version or something along those lines? Where do I need to look and what can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for why we were getting `JDBCException` was simply because the Oracle tablespace in which the table was sitting under was 100% full and, crucially, the tablespace was not set with `autoextend on`.